# How to translate “router” to Esperanto?

Tags: translation, single-word-requests

What is a good translation for the word “[router](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_(computing))”? I've heard the word “[enkursigilo](http://komputeko.net/index_eo.php?vorto=enkursigilo)” before, but I don't fully understand why this word translates to “router”.

Comment: I want to comment on this "enkursigilo". This word comes from Bertin, who made a list of computer terminology in 1985. It derives from an other word from Bertin which is "kurso", which means "route". (You can check this word in Komputeko). I find this very confusing and evitinda. "Kurso" already has a meaning which is a course for teaching something, not a route/channel for data. Creating a new word for this would be more adequate. I find it sad that people are using this word without thinking about it, just because it appears in Komputeko.

Comment: If you want to be very informal about it, how about "retaĵo"?

Comment: I agree "enkursigilo" is a terrible translation. I recommend something like "retdisigilo". I think once we come to a solution we need to approach Komputeko about this.

Comment: @Evildea Vikipedio has "ret-alirilo" as well. Why invent even more new forms? 

Comment: *Datengvidilo, bitgvidmaŝino, bitdirektilo, datenaspergilo...*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I've heard the word “enkursigilo” before, but I don't fully understand why this word translates to “router”.

„kurso” laŭ PIV estas i.a. „Vojlinio, uzata aŭ intencata, por regule kunigi du punktojn”.

Tiu signifo „vojo” ne estis donita al la vorto „kurso” de Bertin, kiel iu ĉi-supre sugestas, sed de Zamenhof mem. Jen kelkaj frazoj liaj: *la poŝtaĵoj estas specigitaj laŭ la germanaj kursoj; la kursoj, kiuj iras al Bremen; la oficistoj devas scii al kiu poŝta kurso ĝi (letero) apartenas; la kurso de aŭtobuso, de kurier-aviadilo, de ŝiplinio.*

Analogie oni parolas pri la kurso de datenoj.

En mia profesia esperantista vivo ni uzis nur la vorton „enkursigilo” en la oficejo. Estus al mi strange post tiom da jaroj subite elekti novan formon.

Comment: Mi opinias same kiel Paŭlo.

Comment: **enkursigi** = _Zorgi ke sendaĵo iru laŭ konvena kurso._[ReVo] Do ("route" = "kurso") jam pli klara per difino de la verbo.

Answer (score 3):

Since *enkursigilo* is used by the dictionaries, I'd take a wild guess that that is the official word. Reta Vortaro also has *kursilo* whereas [Vikipedio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enkursigilo) has *ret-alirilo*.

The explanation in Reta Vortaro is this: "En komputila reto, aranĝaĵo ricevanta mesaĝojn (pakaĵojn), kaj plusendanta ilin al la celata komputilo per preferinda vojo (kurso)."

In English, I guess I'd translate that to "tool, to bring things on their way". (with way understood as "kurso").
[Komputeko](http://komputeko.net/index_nl.php?vorto=router), [Reta Vortaro](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/kurs.html")

Answer (score 1):

The word I tend to use is disvojilo. My experience in practice is that people understand it easily in context, unlike enkursigilo.

Comment: Se vi volus uzi tian terminon, devus temi pri „disvojigilo”, ĉu ne? „voji” ja estas netransivita verbo.

Comment: mi vidas ĝin kiel ilo kiu okupiĝas pri disaj vojoj ;)

Answer (score 0):

Vortaro por komputada leksikono en la reto: enkursigilo
http://bertilow.com/div/komputada_leksikono/

Comment: Bonege! Sed vi ne respondis la demandon. Estus pli bone ankaŭ inkluzivi la ĝustan vorton de la demando, laŭ la ligita vortaro.

Comment: Positiva pri tiu respondo estas ke Komputada Leksikono estas delonge establita, kaj multaj terminoj retroviĝas ReVo.